# R Order only one factor level (or column if after) to affect order long to wide (using spread)

Tags: r, sorting, tidyr, spread

I have a problem after changing my dataset from long to wide (using `spread`, from the tidyr library on the `Result_Type` column). I have the following example df:

```
Group<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D", "D")
Result_Type<-c("Final.Result", "Verification","Test", "Verification","Final.Result","Fast",
               "Verification","Fast", "Final.Result", "Test", "Final.Result")
Result<-c(7,1,8,7,"NA",9,10,12,17,50,11)
df<-data.frame(Group, Result_Type, Result)

df
   Group  Result_Type Result
1      A Final.Result      7
2      A Verification      1
3      A         Test      8
4      B Verification      7
5      B Final.Result     NA
6      B         Fast      9
7      C Verification     10
8      C         Fast     12
9      C Final.Result     17
10     D         Test     50
11     D Final.Result     11
```

In the column `Result_type` there are many possible result types and in some datasets I have Result_Type 's that will not occur in other datasets. However, one level: `Final.Result`does occur in every dataset.

Also: This is example data but the actual data has many different columns, and as these differ across the datasets I use, I used `spread` (from the tidyr library) so I don't have to give any specific column names other than my target columns.

```
library("tidyr")
df_spread<-spread(df, key = Result_Type, value = Result)

  Group Fast Final.Result Test Verification
1     A <NA>            7    8            1
2     B    9           NA <NA>            7
3     C   12           17 <NA>           10
4     D <NA>           11   50         <NA>
```

What I would like is that once I convert the dataset from long to wide, `Final.Result` is the first column, how the rest of the columns is arranged doesn't matter, so I would like it to be like this (without calling any names of the other columns that are spread, or using order index numbers):

```
  Group Final.Result Fast Test Verification
1     A            7 <NA>    8            1
2     B           NA    9 <NA>            7
3     C           17   12 <NA>           10
4     D           11 <NA>   50         <NA>
```

I saw some answers that indicated you can reverse the order of the spreaded columns, or turn off the ordering of spread, but that doesn't make sure that `Final.Result` is always the first column of the `spread` levels.

I hope I am making myself clear, it's a little complicated to explain. If someone needs extra info I will be happy to explain more!

Comment: ow sorry I will also edit my question: from the tidyr library

Comment: Why don't you just add one extra step for the ordering? like `spread(df, key = Result_Type, value = Result) %>% select(Group, Final.Result, everything())`

Comment: Yes only Group is actually also multiple columns with different names in the different datasets, would something like this still work or..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spread` creates columns in the order of the `key` column's factor levels. Within the tidyverse, `forcats::fct_relevel` is a convenience function for rearranging factor levels. The default is that the level(s) you specify will be moved to the front.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

...

levels(df$Result_Type)
#> [1] "Fast"         "Final.Result" "Test"         "Verification"
```

Calling `fct_relevel` will put `"Final.Result"` as the first level, keeping the rest of the levels in their previous order.

```r
reordered <- df %>%
  mutate(Result_Type = forcats::fct_relevel(Result_Type, "Final.Result"))

levels(reordered$Result_Type)
#> [1] "Final.Result" "Fast"         "Test"         "Verification"
```

Adding that into your pipeline puts `Final.Result` as the first column after spreading.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Result_Type = forcats::fct_relevel(Result_Type, "Final.Result")) %>%
  spread(key = Result_Type, value = Result)
#>   Group Final.Result Fast Test Verification
#> 1     A            7 <NA>    8            1
#> 2     B           NA    9 <NA>            7
#> 3     C           17   12 <NA>           10
#> 4     D           11 <NA>   50         <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Ah perfect, didn't know I could use it this way, thank you so much :)!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to refactor `Result_Type` to put `final.result` as the first one:

```
df$Result_Type<-factor(df$Result_Type,levels=c("Final.Result",as.character(unique(df$Result_Type)[!unique(df$Result_Type)=="Final.Result"])))

spread(df, key = Result_Type, value = Result)
  Group Final.Result Verification Test Fast
1     A            7            1    8   NA
2     B           NA            7   NA    9
3     C           17           10   NA   12
4     D           11           NA   50   NA
```

If you'd like you can use this opportunity to also sort the rest of the columns whichever way you want.